# How to list files in first level only for a given directory?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I need to enumerate all first level files with full path in a given directory. How to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 pushd "c:\my_dir"
 for %%a in (*) do echo "%%~fa"
 popd
```

with **DIR** you can list either full paths recursively or first level files so you'll need FOR.

Comment: hi its listing files under current directory. Where can i specify particular directory name?